# Strange Gap Between Two Div Elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

I'm dealing with a weird issue right now. This is my first React website that I've developed and I've been able to figure stuff out on my own for the most part but I can't seem to figure out where this weird gap is coming from. Image is attached below:

[White Image Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWesf.png)

I'm developing a personal site and the content in the upper half of the image is the image that the user is greeted with on landing, width and height are both set to 100%, but when you scroll down I didn't want this gap to exist, I wanted to scroll straight into the About me section. I've tried to adjust the margin of each `div` to no avail (I also tried experimenting with. negative margins and only ever was able to create a weird overlap effect, which I didn't want, picture of this overlap is here: [Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0TFA.png)), and I've also tried to change the background color of the body of the site to get rid of this white gap, but it gives every element of the site the gray-hue that I only wanted in the about me section and below (it also applied the hue to the landing page image, which is not what I wanted). I've attached  the relevant HTML/CSS below, but please let me know if I can provide any more info. Any advice helps!

```
HTML:
<div className='home' id='home'>
// HTML for the landing page in here
</div>


<div className='color_setter'>        
// HTML for the about me section in here    
</div>

CSS:
.roof_pic { // styling for the landing page picture
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.about { // only styling related to the about me section
  /* text-align: center;
  display: grid; */
  margin: 100px;
}
```

Full code found here:

```css
@font-face { font-family: Alata; src: url('fonts/Alata-Regular.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Alata; font-weight: bold; src: url('fonts/Alata-Regular.ttf');}

@font-face { font-family: NTR; src: url('fonts/NTR-Regular.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: NTR; font-weight: bold; src: url('fonts/NTR-Regular.ttf');}

@font-face { font-family: MC; src: url('fonts/minecraft-font/MinecraftRegular-Bmg3.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: MC; font-weight: bold; src: url('fonts/minecraft-font/MinecraftBold-nMK1.otf');}

.color_setter {
  background-color: #222725;
  margin-top: -80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.home {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrappingimage  {  
    float: right;   
    margin: 30px 12px 3px 4px;
}

.abt_picture {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #151818;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

li:before { 
  content: "▹    "; 
  margin-left: -20px; 
  margin-right: 10px; 
  color: #77BA99;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
} 

/* .color_setter {
  background-color: #222725;
} */

.footer_button {
  background-color: #222725; 
  color: white; 
  border: 2px solid #002aff;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.footer_button:hover {
  background-color: #002aff;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #222725;
}

.elden_ring {
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card_wrapper { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .card_wrapper { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }
}

.card_wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card_img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 370px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.7s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}



/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.stroke_text {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

.stroke_text::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #9DACB2;
}


/* SHOWING SOMETHING WHEN ONLY ON MOBILE */
/* #mobile_text {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
  #mobile_text{
    display: block;
  }
 } */

 @media only screen and (max-width:960px){
  .about {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .abt_text {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .wrappingimage {
    display: none;
  }
 }


























.abt_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #9DACB2;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .button {
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}


.wrapper .button:nth-child(1):hover .icon {
  background: #4267B2;
}

.wrapper .button .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button .icon FontAwesomeIcon {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:hover {
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper .button span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}



.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.7s;
}


.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}







* {
  font-family: Alata, sans-serif;
  
  /* margin: 50px; */
}
.about_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/person.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.about_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/personblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.skills_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 70px;
}

.skills_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.portfolio_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 120px;
}

.portfolio_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.resume_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 170px;
}

.resume_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.roof_pic {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.pic_text {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  font-family: NTR, sans-serif;
}

.about {
  /* text-align: center;
  display: grid; */
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #222725;
}

.skills {
  margin: 100px;
}

.portfolio {
  margin: 100px;
}

.resume {
  text-align: center;
}

.pic_text_wrapper {
  z-index: 4;
  /* height: 100vh;
  padding: 150px 75px;
  text-align: center; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#typewriter {
  color: #0072ef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cursor {
  color: #0072ef;
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
      opacity: 100%;
  }
  50% {
      opacity: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className='home' id='home'>

        <picture>
          <source media='(orientation: landscape)' srcSet={roof}></source>
          <source media='(orientation: portrait)' srcSet={portrait}></source>

          <img className='roof_pic' src={roof} alt='roof' height="auto"></img>
        </picture>

        <div className='pic_text_wrapper'>
          <h1>Hey, I'm Tyler<br /> I'm a <span id="typewriter"></span><span id="cursor">|</span>  </h1>
        </div>

      </div>
      
      <div className='color_setter'>        
        <section className='hidden'>
          <div className='about' id='about'>
            <h1 className='stroke_text'>/About me</h1>
            <div className='wrappingimage'>
              <img src={Car} alt='abt_pic' className='abt_picture'></img>
            </div>
            <p className='abt_text'>I am currently an Undergraduate Research Assistant at the Illinois Geometry Lab, working with Radu's Algorithm as it relates to combinatorics. At the same time, I am pursuing a full-time Bachelor's of Science in Computer Science and Mathematics at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.

            Here are some technologies I have been working with:
            <ul>
              <li>Javascript ES6+</li>
              <li>Python</li>
              <li>React.js</li>
              <li>Java</li>
              <li>Node.js</li>
              <li>HTML & CSS</li>
            </ul>
            
Outside of school, I'm interested in following the developments of science, and reading a lot of comics. You might also find me filling up my Github with personal projects</p>
          </div>
        </section>


        <section className='hidden'>
          <div className='skills' id='skills'>
            <h1 className='stroke_text'>/Skills</h1>
            <p><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
          </div>
        </section>


        <section className='hidden'>
          <div className='portfolio' id='portfolio'>

            <h1 className='stroke_text'>/Portfolio</h1>
            <div className='card_wrapper'>
              <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                  <div class="flip-card-front">
                    <img src={collatz} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                    <h1>Collatz Visualization</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <p>The Collatz Visualization was a naive implementation of a model developed by Edmund Harriss to better understand the periodic behavior of the Collatz Conjecture. This implementation was developed in Python using matplotlib and was an introductory exercise to numpy </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                  <div class="flip-card-front">
                    <img src={elden} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                    <h1 className='elden_ring'>Elden Ring Speedrun Optimizer</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <p>Add description of elden ring thing!</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                  <div class="flip-card-front">
                    <img src={handwritten} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                    <h1 className='elden_ring'>Handwritten Digit Recognition</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <p>Add description of handwritten thing!</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                  <div class="flip-card-front">
                    <img src={handwritten} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                    <h1 className='elden_ring'>Handwritten Digit Recognition</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <p>Add description of handwritten thing!</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </section>


        <div className='wrapper'>

          <a href='#about'>
            <div className='button'>
              <a href='#about'><div className='icon'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} /></div></a>
              <span>About me</span>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href='#skills'>
            <div className='button'>
              <a href='#skills'><div className='icon'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAnchor} /></div></a>
              <span>Skills</span>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href='#portfolio'>
            <div className='button'>
              <a href='#portfolio'><div className='icon'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAtom} /></div></a>
              <span>Work</span>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href = {Resume}>
            <div className='button'>
              <a href = {Resume}><div className='icon'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCrow} /></div></a>
              <span>Resume</span>
            </div>
          </a>

        </div>
          
        <footer className='bottom_thing'>
          <a href='#home'><button className='footer_button'>Back to Top!</button></a>
        </footer>
      </div>


</div>
```

As a last point of clarification, this is the effect I'm trying to achieve, without the gray overlap between the image and the about me section:
[Intended Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiaT8.jpg)

Comment: This isn’t a React issue. This is purely a CSS issue. You’re not sharing HTML. You’re sharing JSX. Update your code snippet to use the rendered markup instead.

Comment: @Terry I'm not entirely sure what you mean, the code in the snippet is what's being rendered?

Comment: `className` is a JSX attribute and not HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider:

- Removing the `margin-top: -80px` declaration from the `.color_setter` so there is no more overlap.
- Applying `display: block` to the `.roof_pic` `<img>` element so that there is no whitespace underneath.

```js
const roof = 'https://picsum.photos/1920/1080';
const portrait = 'https://picsum.photos/1080/1920';
const Car = 'https://picsum.photos/1000/1000';
const collatz = 'https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?';
const elden = 'https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?0';
const handwritten = 'https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?1';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <div className="App">
    <div className='home' id='home'>
      <picture>
        <source media='(orientation: landscape)' srcSet={roof}></source>
        <source media='(orientation: portrait)' srcSet={portrait}></source>
        <img className='roof_pic' src={roof} alt='roof' height="auto"></img>
      </picture>

      <div className='pic_text_wrapper'>
        <h1>Hey, I'm Tyler<br /> I'm a <span id="typewriter"></span><span id="cursor">|</span> </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className='color_setter'>
      <section className='hidden'>
        <div className='about' id='about'>
          <h1 className='stroke_text'>/About me</h1>
          <div className='wrappingimage'>
            <img src={Car} alt='abt_pic' className='abt_picture'></img>
          </div>
          <p className='abt_text'>I am currently an Undergraduate Research Assistant at the Illinois Geometry Lab, working with Radu's Algorithm as it relates to combinatorics. At the same time, I am pursuing a full-time Bachelor's of Science in Computer Science and Mathematics
            at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign. Here are some technologies I have been working with:
            <ul>
              <li>Javascript ES6+</li>
              <li>Python</li>
              <li>React.js</li>
              <li>Java</li>
              <li>Node.js</li>
              <li>HTML & CSS</li>
            </ul>

            Outside of school, I'm interested in following the developments of science, and reading a lot of comics. You might also find me filling up my Github with personal projects</p>
        </div>
      </section>


      <section className='hidden'>
        <div className='skills' id='skills'>
          <h1 className='stroke_text'>/Skills</h1>
          <p><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className='hidden'>
        <div className='portfolio' id='portfolio'>
          <h1 className='stroke_text'>/Portfolio</h1>

          <div className='card_wrapper'>
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src={collatz} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                  <h1>Collatz Visualization</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p>The Collatz Visualization was a naive implementation of a model developed by Edmund Harriss to better understand the periodic behavior of the Collatz Conjecture. This implementation was developed in Python using matplotlib and was an introductory
                    exercise to numpy </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src={elden} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                  <h1 className='elden_ring'>Elden Ring Speedrun Optimizer</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p>Add description of elden ring thing!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src={handwritten} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                  <h1 className='elden_ring'>Handwritten Digit Recognition</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p>Add description of handwritten thing!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src={handwritten} className="card_img" alt="Avatar"></img>
                  <h1 className='elden_ring'>Handwritten Digit Recognition</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <p>Add description of handwritten thing!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div className='wrapper'>
        <a href='#about'>
          <div className='button'>
            <a href='#about'>
              <div className='icon'></div>
            </a>
            <span>About me</span>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href='#skills'>
          <div className='button'>
            <a href='#skills'>
              <div className='icon'></div>
            </a>
            <span>Skills</span>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href='#portfolio'>
          <div className='button'>
            <a href='#portfolio'>
              <div className='icon'></div>
            </a>
            <span>Work</span>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="">
          <div className='button'>
            <a href="">
              <div className='icon'></div>
            </a>
            <span>Resume</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <footer className='bottom_thing'>
        <a href='#home'><button className='footer_button'>Back to Top!</button></a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Alata;
  src: url('fonts/Alata-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Alata;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('fonts/Alata-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: NTR;
  src: url('fonts/NTR-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: NTR;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('fonts/NTR-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: MC;
  src: url('fonts/minecraft-font/MinecraftRegular-Bmg3.otf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: MC;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('fonts/minecraft-font/MinecraftBold-nMK1.otf');
}

.color_setter {
  background-color: #222725;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.home {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrappingimage {
  float: right;
  margin: 30px 12px 3px 4px;
}

.abt_picture {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #151818;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

li:before {
  content: "▹    ";
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #77BA99;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* .color_setter {
  background-color: #222725;
} */

.footer_button {
  background-color: #222725;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #002aff;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.footer_button:hover {
  background-color: #002aff;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #222725;
}

.elden_ring {
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card_wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .card_wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card_wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card_img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 370px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.7s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.stroke_text {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

.stroke_text::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #9DACB2;
}


/* SHOWING SOMETHING WHEN ONLY ON MOBILE */


/* #mobile_text {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
  #mobile_text{
    display: block;
  }
 } */

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
  .about {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .abt_text {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .wrappingimage {
    display: none;
  }
}

.abt_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #9DACB2;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .button {
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1):hover .icon {
  background: #4267B2;
}

.wrapper .button .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button .icon FontAwesomeIcon {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:hover {
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper .button span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

* {
  font-family: Alata, sans-serif;
  /* margin: 50px; */
}

.about_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/person.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.about_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/personblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.skills_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 70px;
}

.skills_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.portfolio_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 120px;
}

.portfolio_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.resume_button {
  background-image: url('./icons/skills.png');
  background-size: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 170px;
}

.resume_button:hover {
  background-image: url('./icons/skillsblue.png');
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.roof_pic {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.pic_text {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: NTR, sans-serif;
}

.about {
  /* text-align: center;
  display: grid; */
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #222725;
}

.skills {
  margin: 100px;
}

.portfolio {
  margin: 100px;
}

.resume {
  text-align: center;
}

.pic_text_wrapper {
  z-index: 4;
  /* height: 100vh;
  padding: 150px 75px;
  text-align: center; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#typewriter {
  color: #0072ef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cursor {
  color: #0072ef;
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

.roof_pic {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```